# Python Subprocess Does Not Execute Next Lines

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to get into Python automation.

I have been trying to create a script that:

1. Launches Program
2. Waits for the program to launch
3. Types a string
4. Presses keyboard button

After loading the script, the program launches, but the next line of codes do not execute until I close the program.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()

subprocess.call(['C:\xxx\xxxx\xxxxx.exe'])
print('program launched')

time.sleep(15)
print('timer finished')
keyboard.press(Key.enter)
keyboard.release(Key.enter)
keyboard.type('xxxxxx')
time.sleep(1)
keyboard.press(Key.tab)
keyboard.release(Key.tab)
time.sleep(1)
keyboard.type('xxxxxx')
keyboard.press(Key.enter)
keyboard.release(Key.enter)
```

Answer (score 1):

I learned that subprocess.call waits for the program to exit, before continuing next line of code.
subprocess.Popen will execute the code, open the program and carryon to the next lines of code.